# can slightly and too come together?

Tags: collocations

> The hydrogen adsorption free energy on sulfided Mo edges for MoS2 (ΔGGH = 80 meV) is slightly too weak.

is the phrase "slightly too weak" ok here?

"Slightly" means 'to a small degree" while "too" means "to a higher degree". So I am not sure whether this combination is correct.

Comment: It's fine. I might ask "Slightly too weak for what?", though.

Comment: You need to provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like what you **think** this means, and what you **intend** to convey. We can't guarantee that you are expressing yourself correctly without more information.

Comment: "Slightly" means 'to a small degree" while "too" means "to a higher degree". So I am not sure whether this combination is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your phrase

> slightly too weak

is perfectly understandable and correct with the meaning of

> weaker than weak, but not quite as weak as too weak
>
> The car is *slightly too weak* to pull the boat, if the boat was 10 pounds lighter it would work.
>
> At 4 foot 11 inches, David is *slightly too short* for the 5 foot ride.

In order of weakness

> weak
>   slightly too weak
>   too weak

just as in

> expensive  *($100)*
>   slightly too expensive  *($500)*
>   too expensive *($1,000)*
>   much too expensive *($10,000)*
>   very much too expensive *($100,000)*
>   Holy Cow! *($1,000,000)*

The use of "slightly" (less) partially cancels out the use of "too" (more).

Comment: The explanation is really helpful